# Scaled textures distorted while moving

Tags: java, libgdx

I create a game in libGDX and have problem with scaling textures, which I have to use because of the different screen resolutions.
When these textures move on screen, there is a distortion. You can see it on the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Mo_LFWsuHs
It can be seen well at the markings on boxes.

I tried with TextureFilter.LINEAR and used both Texture and TextureRegion but with no result.
I also read on the Internet that it's a problem with Java - so do I have to change libGDX to other, not Java-based framework?

Comment: How do you move your textures?Camera moves or textures? Did you use interpolation for moving?

Comment: It's not a problem with Java. What dimensions are the original Texture? You'll need to use mip mapping if you're drawing it smaller than its original size.

Comment: Camera moves, texture is scaled down (662x694 to 182x192 pixels). Interpolation - you mean this? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interpolation If yes, I didn't use it.